# running exec command in php does not function

Tags: php, exec

I am having a problem running this command inside of php's exec command:

UPDATED WORKING CODE:

```
$results = exec('curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data @data.json https://website.url --insecure', $output);
if ($results) {
    echo "yay!";
    var_dump($output);
    echo $results;
} else {
    var_dump($output);
    echo "screw you";   
}
```

originally the script together works in linux but inside php exec the inside single quotes conflicted with php's exec quotes. previous script:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"data": "foo", "data2": "bar"}' https://website.url
```

I'm wondering what might solve this quotes problem, I thought the `escapeshellarg()` might do it but to no avail.

**Update:**

Error from Error page

> PHP Warning:  escapeshellarg() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Compared to your previous command, you seem to be missing spaces with around your json data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo. Use the `[]` to access the `$_POST` array instead of `()`. Otherwise name and pass would being empty what will break the command line. Further **you'll have to escape incoming posts before using it in a shell command**. Otherwise the code is vulnerable for shell cmd injections (what is fatal):

```
$postname = escapeshellarg($_POST['name']);
$postpass = esacpeshellarg($_POST['pass']);
```

Also you are missing the spaces before and after the json data. Change it to:

```
$results = exec('curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '.escapeshellarg($jsondata). ' https://website.url');
```

After that changes the example works for me. But you should note about the [php curl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). I would use it instead of calling curl via `exec()`

Comment: we had tried that but to no avail :( we are interfacing with tastypies rest system.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test without having an account there. Have you tried using the curl extension? You'll find a ton of examples online. But can help if you need

Comment: Can you add the exact url you are trying to the question?

Comment: I can not as it includes a api key and secret but the url is not the problem, the problem comes when I try to input the json data

Comment: ok sorry was afk for a bit but I updated the code and put a error return check in there and I get this: array(0) { }

Comment: Sorry a copy/paste error.. replace `print` by `exec`.. (check the edit)

Comment: heres from the error page on the server, which is interesting.... PHP Warning:  escapeshellarg() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: I'm actually feeding it static data in $jsondata 'data': 'foo', 'data2': 'bar' to test right now and its spitting out those errors

Comment: Can you post your actual code to pastebin? (without API key) ?

Comment: So I believe the issue if you look at the original linux command is with the json data there are '' single quotes around it and those are required for the data to be read on the server side and php does not like them cause it already has '' single quotes inside the exec command. my thought was that escapeshellarg should solve this problem but it does not.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the PHP Warning. The code works perfectly expect of `Couldn't resolve host 'userurl.revelup.com'`

Comment: the url works though in linux when executed from a command line.

Comment: I **cannot** ping that host. Seems that you are lost in confusion. However, the code (on pastebin) works. The only error was the missing space after `data`

Comment: userurl is not the real url, sorry their policy will not allow me to give it out.

Comment: I think I will just have to find an alternative command to do this then, nothing is working due to those quotes. :(

Comment: original code must be exact or it fails, curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"data": "foo", "data2": "bar"}' https://website.url notice single quotes after --data those must stay there. they mess up with php due to the single quotes that are there from the exec function.

Comment: Note, that I am using a Linux system and have tested the code successfully hours ago. (with different url of course). I cannot help any further as I see no problem. If you use the code from pastebin it will work

Comment: woot! got it to work. I'm updating the code above to new working code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jsondata = '{"data":"'.$_POST['name'].'", "data2":"'.$_POST['pass'].'"}';
$command  = "curl --dump-header - -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X PUT --data '$jsondata' https://website.url";
$results = exec($command);
```